# Vagrant box won't up when hosted but OK locally

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am hosting my box at wayne-o/xubuntu-md - the file is located on my dropbox share.

Now - if I add this file locally using `vagrant box add st package.box` I can see the box is added as st to my list of local boxes.

Now - if I try and use the uploaded box using

```
config.vm.box = "wayne-o/xubuntu-md"
```

I get the following error:

```
The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
file you're trying to add is not corrupted and try again. The
output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

bsdtar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: It looks like you added a wrong link to vagrantcloud. Looking at https://vagrantcloud.com/wayne-o/boxes/xubuntu-md/versions, the link to your box is https://vagrantcloud.com/wayne-o/boxes/xubuntu-md/versions/3/providers/virtualbox.box which redirects to dropbox but gives a 404.

Comment: Still, it's not the link to the box but to the page where you can download the box. Try using https://www.dropbox.com/s/86m4h2r70mowtse/package.box?dl=1

Comment: Good to notice that one of the parameters sent in the link is `dl=1` which makes it a [_Direct Link_](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/201) that forces an automatic download. Dropbox sets this to `dl=0` by default so people can see the file on the browser _before_ downloading.

Comment: That dl param has stung me on more than a few occasions!